# Only increment one item inside ngFor (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm trying to create a little shopping cart with ionic 2 and angular 2. For now, here is my code :

Front :

```
 <ion-card *ngFor="let person of people;let i = index" >

        <ion-card-header>{{person.name.first}} {{person.name.last}} {{i}}</ion-card-header>

        <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="add-circle" (click)="incrementQty(i)" item-right></ion-icon>
        <ion-input type="number" min="1" [value]="qty" [(ngModel)]="qty"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon name="remove-circle"(click)="decrementQty(i)" item-right></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

.ts file :

```
incrementQty(index:number){
  console.log(this.people[index]);
  this.qty += 1;
}
```

My problem is that I only want to increment the clicked element, not all of them !

I'm new to angular 2 and don't know how to manage this problem, so thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two possible solutions:

**Option-1**

Let `qty` be a property of the `person` object and in your `incrementQty` method do `this.people[index].qty += 1`

```
private quantities: number[];

constructor() {
  this.people = this.people.map(person => {
     person['qty'] = 0;
     return person
  });
}

incrementQty(index:number){
  this.people[index].qty += 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let person of people;let i = index" >

        <ion-card-header>{{person.name.first}} {{person.name.last}} {{i}}</ion-card-header>

        <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="add-circle" (click)="incrementQty(i)" item-right></ion-icon>
        <ion-input type="number" min="1" [value]="person.qty" [(ngModel)]="person.qty"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon name="remove-circle"(click)="decrementQty(i)" item-right></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

**Option-2**

Create an array of `qty` in the (maybe in the `constructor`) component code. The size of the array should be same as the size of the `people` array. Set initial values to 0. In your code, you can increment the quantity in the array at index same as index of person in people array.

```
private quantities: number[];

constructor() {
  this.quantities = new Array(this.people.length);
  this.quantities= this.quantities.map((el: any) => 0);
}

incrementQty(index:number){
  this.quantities[index] += 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let person of people;let i = index" >

        <ion-card-header>{{person.name.first}} {{person.name.last}} {{i}}</ion-card-header>

        <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="add-circle" (click)="incrementQty(i)" item-right></ion-icon>
        <ion-input type="number" min="1" [value]="quantities[i]" [(ngModel)]="quantities[i]"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon name="remove-circle"(click)="decrementQty(i)" item-right></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! The option 1 does the job very nicely !!

Answer (score 1):

You need a `qty` value per `person`, currently you have only one for the entire component.

```ts
qty:number[];


loadPeople(){ 
  this.peopleService.load()
  .then(data => { 
    this.people = data; 
    this.qty = new Array(this.people.length);
  }); 
}

incrementQty(index:number){
  console.log(this.people[index]);
  this.qty[index] += 1;
}
```

```ts
<ion-card *ngFor="let person of people;let i = index" >

        <ion-card-header>{{person.name.first}} {{person.name.last}} {{i}}</ion-card-header>

        <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="add-circle" (click)="incrementQty(i)" item-right></ion-icon>
        <ion-input type="number" min="1" [value]="qty[i]" [(ngModel)]="qty[i]"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon name="remove-circle"(click)="decrementQty(i)" item-right></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Actually, "people" is the result of my provider "PeopleService". I tried you answer but I've got an error : Cannot read property 'length' of undefined... That's strange because I have load my provider before the this.qty = new Array(this.people.length)

Comment: I would need to see the code to be able to tailor the answer more to your actual situation.

Comment: this is my function to call my provider :

 loadPeople(){
  this.peopleService.load()
  .then(data => {
    this.people = data;
    
  });
}

Comment: Thank you :) The answer of Santanu Biwas work perfectly, but I keep you solution in mind ;)